# Setting up a local server for SQLite database - Android

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sqlite, local

I've created a pre-made database in SQLite for an Android app I'm developing. The app should interact and pull data from the database and display it on different 'Intents'. For now I just want to set up a local server on my Windows Computer for the database. 
I was wondering what is the best way of doing so? I have little to no experience with setting up local servers or anything with regards to servers.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as an SQLite "server". SQLite runs locally only through libraries. Also, Android database connections can not simply connect to anything on a server.

If you need a database on a server and an Android client to manipulate the data, you need to implement some kind of client-server architecture, for example using (RESTful) WEB services or any other client-server-communication.